# Dynamic folder creation and multiple file upload to the server using angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

is it possible to create an angular app like Filezilla or core FTP to upload files and folders to the server using ftp?
I have to upload files and folders to the server by using the admin panel rather than FileZilla or any other app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should create a web API and post the files to that, then make your web API upload the files to the actual FTP server.

Use a

```html
<input type="file">
```

to get pick the files or create a drag/drop component.
Add the files to a form, and add that form as body to a HTTP post request

```js
constructor(http: HttpClient) {}

uploadFile(file: File) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (file) {
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        
        http.post('myApiURL', formData).pipe(take(1)).subscribe()
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept this as the answer then, otherwise your question will stay open forever